# What is the difference between billing account and financial account in tmforum open-api account management service specs

Tags: openapi, finance

I am just trying out the open-API specs provided by tmforum https://www.tmforum.org/open-apis/ and cannot seem to figure out the difference and actual purpose of the financial account resource mentioned in account management API specs. Can someone please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The financial account aggregates the amounts of one or more billing accounts owned by a given party. For example, as a customer, I may have multiple billing accounts (e.g. for broadband services for multiple properties) - the financial account is the aggregation of these billing accounts.